# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|<\infty \Rightarrow F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x^k $ is differentiable function $F:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|<\infty \Rightarrow F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x^k $ is differentiable function $F:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$

### The hints we got in the course are "parameter-Integral" and "counting-measure"

In our lecture we had the following theorem:

Let $(S,A,\mu)$ be a measure space, $U\subseteq R^d$ open, $i \in \{1,2,... ,d\}$ with

(i) $f$ is partially differentiable wrt. $u_i$

(ii) $\forall u \in U: x \mapsto f(u,x)$ is $\mu$ - integrable

(iii) $\exists g \ge 0: \int g d\mu<\infty $ and $ \forall u \in U \forall x \in S: |\frac{d f}{du_i}(u,x)|\le g(x) $

Then $F(u):= \int f(u,x) d\mu(x)$  is partially differentiable wrt. $u_i$

---

So I want to use this theorem to show that $F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x^k $ is differentiable

$F$ can we writen as integral using the counting measure $\mu$ : $\int_\mathbb{N} f(k,x) d\mu(k)$

with $f(k,x)=a_k x^k$ with $k \in \mathbb N, x\in (-1+\epsilon, 1-\epsilon) $ for $\epsilon>0$

now I check the conditions for this theorem:

$U=(-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$ is open

(i) $f$ is partially differentiable wrt $x$ ($\frac{df}{dx}=k\cdot a_k x^{k-1}$)

(ii) $\forall x \in (-1+\epsilon, 1-\epsilon) : \int_\mathbb{N} |a_k x^k| d\mu(k) \le \int_\mathbb{N} |a_k| d\mu(k) <\infty$  so we have that $f$ is integrable

(iii) since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|<\infty$ the sequence $a_k$ has to limit $0$, Therefore it is bounded. And I would choose $g$ as $\max(a_k)$
But I'm then probably failing with $\int g d\mu < \infty $ ??

Comment: A convergent power series is differentiable, no?

Comment: @uniquesolution. True... but i have to make a proof using this theorem.

Comment: put $g(k)=k|a_k|(1-\epsilon)^k$ then $|f(x,k)|\le g$ and since $\lim_k k(1-\epsilon)^k=0$ this sequence is bounded, hence $g$ is integrable.

Comment: @Hamza I beat you by a few seconds but thank you for inserting the forgotten $k$

Comment: HHHHHHHHHHH true

Answer (score 1):

$$g(k):=k|a_k|(1-\epsilon)^k\ge\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(k,x)\right|\quad\forall x\in(-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$$
and
$$\sum_k k|a_k|(1-\epsilon)^k<\infty.$$